# How to query in Mongodb where field is an aggregated expression?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

This seems like a simple question but I couldn't find an answer. This is very easy to do in SQL.

I want to query mongodb by searching for a value that is a combination of two fields. For example I want to search for documents where `fieldA + fieldB == ID01`

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
collection.find({{$concat:[$fieldA, $fieldB]}: 'ID01'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using aggregate framework -

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
      { $project: { newField: { $concat: [ "$fieldA", "$fieldB" ] }, fieldA: 1, fieldB: 1 } },
      { $match: { newField: 'ID01' } }
   ]
)
```

Comment: This works but it only returns `newField`. I'd like to return all (or other additional) fields from the original document which contains `fieldA` and `fieldB`. How do I add that in the expression?

Comment: @kyc12,
Check the updated answer.
And if it solves your issue, mark it correct.